# How exactly does an AWS Application Load Balancer perform health checks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have one webserver instance behind an ALB that is in two AZs (since the ALB requires two AZs). For some time, we were getting a result of .5 healthy instances in our monitoring.

Eventually we were able to solve this by modifying security group rules to allow all traffic from the ALB security group to go to the webserver ports, and now we have consistent health check success.

My question is this: do the health checks alternate between the ALB instances that live in different AZs? I'm just curious as to how it is possible to end up with .5 of the health checks passing, and my guess is that only one of the ALB instances was able to access the webserver instance before our security group rule change that explicitly allowed all traffic on port 80 from the ALB sg.

Comment: You’re probably seeing 0.5 healthy instances because it’s giving you an average number of healthy instances for some time period.